# How do I create a calculated column that displays Yes or No if ANY other columns in the row have the value "Yes"?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, modern-experience

I have a series of 3 Choice columns that are populated by a MS Form to be either "Yes" or "No". I am wanting Column4 to show Yes if ANY of the columns 1 2 or 3 contain the value "Yes"

What is the formula to do so? It keeps telling me that the columns don't exist or the formula is unsupported.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF([Column1]="yes","yes",IF([Column2]="yes","yes", IF([Column3]="yes","yes","no")))
```

Test result:
[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 0):

You can use **OR** function to test upto 30 conditions at time. Use below formula for your case:

```
=IF(OR([Column 1] = "Yes", [Column 2] = "Yes", [Column 3] = "Yes"), "Yes", "No")
```

Keep in mind that in calculated column formulas you have to use **Display name** of your columns and it is always recommended to use column name inside `[]` if it contains special characters like space.

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Return your calculated field as **Single line of text**.

**official documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)).
2. [IF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-7025be14-5665-43d0-af20-8293d1fe9d3a).
3. [OR function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/or-function-9a2a1cca-696f-4d19-a959-3943babd076f)